# Interrupt a accept() that is waiting, just changing a global variable value

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads, signals

I'm doing a project for university, a chat system with a server and multiple clients.

In the specification document there is written:

> The main thread does a controlled loop on the global var go, and at each cycle waits for a connection request by an user

And also:

> Server stops with SIGTERM or SIGINT. When signal is received, the global var go is set to zero, and all threads exit from the loop cycle

So, the `thread main` create the socket, bind the port and at every new connection does an `accept()` and create a `thread worker` which takes care of the communication with the client.

My problem is exiting the `thread main` only changing the global var.
In the `thread main` if I do

```
while (go && accept(params)) {}
```

it doesn't enter in the while loop.

So at the moment the code is

```
while (go) {
    accept(params);
    // Do stuff
}
```

And, well, when I set `go` to zero it waits on `accept`, so I have to create a new connection, it accepts the connection and then exit the thread 'cause `go` becomes zero.

Same problem with `thread worker`

```
while (go && read(socket_id, buffer, sizeof(char)) > 0) {}
```

It waits for a char from the socket to exit the loop.

I don't see a way to exit loops using only the `go` var.
I think I've to close the socket, or find another way, am I wrong?

*I'm not interested in other ways to exit threads, just to know if it's possible to exit loops just changing the go var*

Thanks!

Comment: `listen` doesn't block. Did you mean `accept`?

Comment: @immibis right, sorry, let me update the question. Done

Comment: How do you toggle `go`?

Comment: @alk I've a signal handler in the main() function. It works well, because when I set it to 0 others while(go) (that don't have an accept or a read inside) exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you setup a signal handler for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` to toggle the `go` to `!=0` you also want to unset the `SA_RESTART` flag for the handler(s), which would make `accept()` return `-1` on the signal's reception.

To do so setup the signal handler using [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). For the `struct sigaction` you pass in do not set the member `sa_flags` to hold `SA_RESTART`.

For a detailed description which system call is influenced by the `SA_RESTART` flag see section "***Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers***" of [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

---

Independendly from this make sure `go` is defined `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: WOW, thanks!

I learned so much from this answer :-)

It works well, indeed, and I've also new things to read and learn! Thanks again!